# Lombok Plugin Does not Working In Latest Version Of Android Studio (Bumblebee)

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, lombok

I use **Lombok** in my project and recently Update my Android Studio To the latest version (**Bumblebee**) And The Lombok Plugin doesn't work, is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: me too facing the same issue

Answer (score 9, accepted):

not a resolution but there is a (working) workaround in the comments of the issue on [github](https://github.com/mplushnikov/lombok-intellij-plugin/issues/1107#issuecomment-1024174446).

Answer (score 4):

For some reason just downloading the latest version from github releases and installing to android studio did not work (it continue to throw the incompatible error).

What actually worked for me (and some of the users reported on github too) is to download the latest release 0.34.1-2019.1 and update the xml configuration and change 'until-build' property to IE-212.* and then importing through 'install from disk'.

Step by step guidance is available in this tutorial

https://youtu.be/A14hrtUeNWU

Comment: It worked just fine.

Answer (score 3):

I created a repository for this problem, which automatically exports the built-in Lombok plugin from IDEA Ultimate, hope it can help you: [lombok-plugin-repository](https://github.com/sgpublic/lombok-plugin-repository)

Answer (score 2):

For Bumblebee, you need the [lombok-211.7628.21 plugin](https://github.com/mplushnikov/lombok-intellij-plugin/files/8130713/lombok-211.7628.21.zip) installed.

Also, Take a [Look at the first comment in this issue in the Lombok GitHub repository](https://github.com/mplushnikov/lombok-intellij-plugin/issues/1111#issue-1148968765) for downloading the plugin for **OTHER VERSIONS** of Android studio.

You can use the following instructions to install plugins in any of the JetBrains products including Android Studio:

- Open the settings for the IDE and select Plugins.
- Then in the options menu, select `install Plugin from Disk`
- Next locate the downloaded file and click OK.

The changes should be applied after you restart your IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Follow bellow steps to resolve your problem:

1 - First download last version of lombok through the [link](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6317-lombok/versions).

2- In Android studio select File -> Settings -> Plugins

3- click on Setting icon and select install plugin from disk.

[image]

4- finally select the downloaded file and after completion restart Android studio.

done!